# Afquickfield Validation

Tags: meteor-autoform

hello guys I have a autoform quickfield. I need to enter url and if the user enter something other than url it should not allow but my validation is not working. My code is given below

```
  <div class="col s12">
     <label for="article-type" class="article-label">Article Source</label>
     {{> afQuickField name='url'}}
  </div>
```

and the field in the schema is like this

```
url: {
    type: String,
    optional: true,
    // label: "Article Source URL",
    autoform:{
      label: false,
      afFieldInput: {
        type: "url",
        pattern: "http://+.",
        placeholder: "Article Source URL",
      }
    }
  }
```

I am doing this by keeping in mind that when the field type is url the validation is applied implicitly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `regEx` option.

```
url: {
  type: String,
  optional: true,
  regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Url,
  autoform:{
    label: false,
    afFieldInput: {
      type: "url",
      placeholder: "Article Source URL",
    }
  }
}
```